# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null on jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my code

```
$.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost:42046/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
       type: 'get',
       success: function (data) {
       $("#fillme").html(data);
      }
});
```

when I remove the `$("#fillme").html(data);` the error goes.

html

```
<span id="fillme"></span>
```

Comment: What is inside `data`?

Comment: @Kiril this is `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>`

Comment: HelloWorld? u might be missing the `.php` extension.

Comment: @rockStar no no, i am using asp. and the web service is executing perfectly, i can see it from my google chrome debugging tool (f12)

Comment: it should work if you provided the correct string. See http://jsfiddle.net/ZmCTe/ . Are you sure that it's not encoded?

Comment: @Kiril no no no encoding. it is just hello world example. also, i am putting that code into a function called roma and i called that function when a button click. does that matter?

Comment: This should work, are you sure #fillme is existant at the moment of execution?

Comment: Maybe you need `dataType : 'xml'` in `.ajax()` options ?

Comment: Try to execute `$("#fillme")` separately inside `success` callback. Does it return the correct DOM node?

Comment: @BatuZet I tried that but still got the same exception.

Comment: @Kiril I tried that `success: function (data) {
                    $("#fillme").html("roma");
                }` and it gives me the `roma` string

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, what browser do you use?

Comment: @Kiril chrome and firefox on windows 7

Comment: Try to change `$("#fillme").html(data);` to `$("#fillme").text(data);`. Also what is jQuery version?

Comment: @Kiril this is the jquery `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js` and when i changed to `text` i didn't get that error, but I got this results `[object Document]`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, so it seems that you obtain not a plain string but an xml structure that is parsed inside jQuery ajax. I think you'll see it if just execute `http://localhost:42046/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld` in browser. I would recommend to review your web-service and make it to return data in a correct format (I'm not sure what exactly do you need but it seems like string). Also try to change $.ajax parameters (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), pay attention to `contents`, `converters `.

Comment: @Kiril type an ansewr please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that the problem is in parsing the xml from the web-service.
You'll see it if just execute `http://localhost:42046/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld` in browser. I would recommend to review your web-service and make it to return data in a correct format (I'm not sure what exactly do you need but it seems like string). Also try to change `$.ajax` parameters (api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax), pay attention to `contents`, `converters`.